# How to get Alert ( of EMA crossing VWAP) on Multiple Stock that are added in my Wishlist using pinescript. I tried using crossover but that failed

Tags: alert, pine-script

```
indicator("Dynamic alert",overlay= true)

emaValue = ta.ema(close,5)
vwapValue = ta.vwap(hlc3)

f_triggerBuy(_ticker)=>

if (crossover(emaValue, vwapValue))
_msg := "EMA5 Crossed VWAP, BUY !! BUY!! BUY!!", alert.freq_all
alert(_msg)
        
if (crossunder(emaValue, vwapValue))
_msg := "VWAP Crossed EMA, SELL !! SELL!! SELL!!", alert.freq_all
alert(_msg)
    
plot(emaValue, title="EMA",color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(vwapValue, title="VWAP", color=color.black, linewidth=2)
          
 //custom function called  
f_triggerBuy(syminfo.tickerid)
f_triggerBuy("NSE:RTNINDIA")
f_triggerBuy("NSE:AEGISCHEM")
f_triggerBuy("NSE:KARURVYSYA")
f_triggerBuy("NSE:KPRMILL")
f_triggerBuy("NSE:PRIVISCL")
```

//getting the following error
// Mismatched input 'f_triggerBuy' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.
// Crossover and Crossunder are not working here.

Answer (score 0):

It means you didn't manage correctly the tabulations

Also, don't forgot to add the //@version=5 at the top of your script

```
f_triggerBuy(_ticker)=>

    if (ta.crossover(emaValue, vwapValue))
        _msg := "EMA5 Crossed VWAP, BUY !! BUY!! BUY!!")
        alert(_msg, alert.freq_all)
            
    if (ta.crossunder(emaValue, vwapValue))
        _msg := "VWAP Crossed EMA, SELL !! SELL!! SELL!!")
        alert(_msg, alert.freq_all)
        
plot(emaValue, title="EMA",color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(vwapValue, title="VWAP", color=color.black, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're going to wanna trigger a buy only on a 5ema >close< above vwap or you'll find yourself losing money on pop & drops when price fails to break